# PHP Get Page Not Working

Tags: php

```
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'myProfile') {     // Account Profile
        $page = 'myProfile';
    } else {                                                        // Dashboard
        $page = 'dashboard';
    }

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'coupon') {        // Settings
        $page = 'settings';
    } else {                                                        // Dashboard
        $page = 'dashboard';
    }
```

The code above,
If i go to ?page=myProfile it leads to the dashboard rather myProfile same for the settings one?

There is code further down that leads myProfile to the .php file etc.

If i remove the 2nd bit of the code (settings) the account profile bit works?
This is using a framework called FrameWorx

Comment: Why don't you just use a `switch` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second `if` rewrites value of `$page` which has been set in previous `if`. Change your `if`s to this, for example:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'myProfile') {
    $page = 'myProfile';
} elseif (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'coupon') {
    $page = 'settings';
} else {
    $page = 'dashboard';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are first setting the $page variable, and in the second you potentially overwrite that same variable.

Try using a switch in stead of an if. This makes it a lot cleaner and easier to understand.

```
if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = 'dashboard';
} 

switch($_GET['page']) {
    case 'myProfile':
         $page = 'myProfile';
    break;
    case 'coupon':
         $page = 'settings';
    break;
    default:
         $page = 'dashboard';
}
```